# Model matrices in R, for mixed models

Tags: r, matrix, lme4, mixed-models

I'm writing my own software package for a certain type of mixed models in R and would like an easy and efficient way to form design matrices. The fixed part ("X") is not a problem, I use `model.matrix`, or `sparse.model.matrix` from the Matrix package if I want it sparse.

I'm looking for an equivalent function, preferably in a well tested package, to create the random effects design matrix ("Z").

For example, if I fit an lmer / glmer model using the lme4 package, I can get the desired matrix by calling `getME(fitted_object, "Zt")`, but I don't want to fit a model just to get the "Zt" or Z matrix. Ideally, I would like to call (e.g) `model.matrix.random(formula)` and get it directly, for any valid formula.

In response to a discussion in the comments, ideas about how such a function could be programmed are also welcome, but I was hoping there would be a well tested implementation already. I tried looking through the source code for lme4 to see how they do it but wasn't able to find the relevant code.

Comment: Just to clarify, the main problem is that one factor level is dropped in `model.matrix(~ 0 + my_factor1 + my_factor2)`? If so, `cbind`ing the results of `model.matrix(~ 0 + my_factor1)` and `model.matrix(~ 0 + my_factor2)` might be an option?

Comment: @coffeinjunky, yep, that works in this particular case. I'm looking for something more general, that handles all possible random effect formulas. I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel and was hoping it was already implemented.

Comment: Could you specify which cases are not covered by this approach?

Comment: @coffeinjunky I'm not quite sure what the approach is, but I think what you're suggesting is to parse a formula statement term by term and then cbinding everything together. I don't know whether there are cases not handled by that approach. What I'm looking for though is an actual implementation to use in software. I'll clarify my question a bit.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at `lme4::lFormula`? That should return the model frame without fitting the model.

Comment: Or to just look at random terms perhaps see `?lme4::mkReTrms`? @BenBolker

Comment: Hi @ekvall, did you solve this problem? Because I'm also looking for a possibility to create a sparse design matrix for random effects (for any valid formula)..